# Which Three20 view should I use after a thumbnail is clicked to produce an Instagram look?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I successfully followed instructions on getting a Three20 photo gallery created.  However, when I click a thumbnail it behaves like the native Photo App. Is this functionality easily overridden? When I click the thumbnail I want to produce a view like the image below.

[image: Desired View after clicking on thumbnail]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is, none of the views provided by Three20 would directly do the trick. Instagram implemented such a view by heavily customizing Cocoa Touch's UITableView. If you want the same style, you will have to roll up your sleeves and implement it by yourself.